# Can't create PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

I had debian system with postgres 9.1.x installed from debian packages, I needed to install pldebugger.

So installed postgresql 9.1.9 from source with pldebbuger.
Started posgresql with 'old' postgres data directory.

Now I'm trying to create new databese 'test_test'

Everythings look fine:

```
psql -U postgres --list

... test_test             | postgres        | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 |
en_US.UTF-8 | ...
```

But when i try to access that DB, i get error:

> FATAL:  database "test_test" does not exist DETAIL:  The database
>   subdirectory "base/48433052" is missing.

Why Postgres can not create new database files?

Comment: How exactly did you install the pldebugger? Something certainly sounds pretty busted.

Comment: I have downloaded pldebugger, extracted to postgresql-9.1.9/contrib/, make make install. Debugger works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by recreating template1 db:

> update pg_database set datistemplate = FALSE where datname =
>   'template1'; drop database template1; create database template1 with
>   template = template0 encoding = 'UTF8'; update pg_database set
>   datistemplate = TRUE where datname = 'template1';